Showing Tests in Dokka html output (Kotlin project)
I am having trouble trying to show my tests in html output with Dokka.
I have tried this code in my build.gradle without any affect:
tasks.withType<DokkaTask>().configureEach {
    dokkaSourceSets {
        named("test") {
            sourceRoots.from(file("src/test/kotlin"))
        }
    }
}


I have also tried this as well:
tasks.dokkaHtml.configure {
    dokkaSourceSets {
        named("test") {
            sourceRoots.from(file("src/test/kotlin")) // Ensure the test root directory is set
            includeNonPublic.set(true) // Include private and internal elements
            documentedVisibilities.set(
                setOf(
                    org.jetbrains.dokka.DokkaConfiguration.Visibility.PUBLIC,
                    org.jetbrains.dokka.DokkaConfiguration.Visibility.PROTECTED,
                    org.jetbrains.dokka.DokkaConfiguration.Visibility.INTERNAL,
                    org.jetbrains.dokka.DokkaConfiguration.Visibility.PRIVATE
                )
            )
            displayName.set("Tests") // Display name in the documentation
        }
    }
}

I am using intelliJ and am using the latest version of Dokka plug-in.  Any help appreciated!!

I received some help in the Kotlin slack group and this addition to the build.gradle allowed the tests to populate in dokkaHtml:
tasks.dokkaHtml {
dokkaSourceSets {
    named("test") {
        suppress.set(false)
        displayName.set("Test Documentation")
    }
}}

